# Old OCR application not working in newer enviroment

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to follow the following old youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kjdu8SjEtG0

After importing and installing packages and copy and pasting code I have many errors.

I believe the problem is the imports are newer and the code referenced is for an older package.

Can anyone help with getting the code to work in a modern environment? Thanks

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.OCR
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure

Public Class Form1

    Dim OCRz As Tesseract = New Tesseract("tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY)
    Dim pic As Bitmap = New Bitmap(270, 100)
    Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        'If Windows XP
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Me.Location.X + PictureBox1.Location.X + 4, Me.Location.Y + PictureBox1.Location.Y + 30), New Point(0, 0), pic.Size)
        PictureBox1.Image = pic

        'If Windows 7
        'gfx.CopyFromScreen(MousePositi­on, New Point(0, 0), pic.Size)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        OCRz.Recognize(New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(pic))
        RichTextBox1.Text = OCRz.GetText

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Did you install the x32 bit version, or the x64 bit version? If  you install the x64 bit version, then you have to set/force your project to run and  compile as x64 bits.

Comment: In tools nuget there is not an option between 32 and 64 bit

Comment: ok, just looking, the .net library does not used un-managed c++ code like it did at one time. As a result, bit size should not matter.

Comment: What's going wrong?

Comment: Have no idea. but you have provide more details about what DOES work. Can you create a blank new project. Install the lib via nuget,and  say then create a instance of the OCR library? Without details outlining what you attempted and what works, and what does not? We can only guess like I did. We don't even know if in a blank new project you are even able to create a instance of the class. So try a few simple things, and then when you encounter something that don't work, you can pose a question that is bite sized and suitable for a Q+A forum. Blind guessing is really all we can offer right now.